# .NET 5 with Angular 11 hosted in Azure Web App

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, .net-5

We are using Angular 11 within .NET 5 and we get this error:

> The stylesheet https://oursites.azurewebsites.net/styles.032ce633d4ce5bc55182.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

My `Index.html` file looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>RedParts</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/assets/images/favicon.png">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i">
```

How to fix this? Does the Azure Web app support Angular v11.0?

Comment: Angular 11 is just a JS library so *of course* it's supported as browsers are the ones to render JS and not Azure. You need to look at your startup configuration as something is wrong and you're likely getting `index.html` as a result instead of the appropriate file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Dot Net core project startup.cs file needs to add up the code to solve the issue.

````
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)(
 
 var staticPath = Path.Combine(
                        Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"ClientApp/dist/app");
                    var fileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                    { FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(staticPath) };
                    app.UseSpaStaticFiles(options: fileOptions);

                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = fileOptions;
```
````